# jquery $.post, to django view method, request.method shows GET, and cannot retrieve parameters

Tags: django, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to figure out how I can send some data to a view in django vis POST, and return some data, depending on the data sent in the request, from the view to the client via an `HttpResponse`.

When the POST request is sent from the client, the web console prints,

```
POST http://<myurl>
GET  http://<myurl>/
```

And the message returned is "get".  In the view method, When I try to access the parameters via `response.GET.get("key")`, `None` is returned.

I must be misunderstanding something, anyone know what is going on?

views.py

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse

    def test(request):

        msg = ""

        if request.method == "POST":
            msg = "post"

        elif request.method == "GET":
            msg = "get"

        return HttpResponse(msg)
```

javascrip/jquery

```
  function _req(url, params, callback ) {

    function onResponse( data ) {
      console.log( data );    
      callback(data);
    };

    $.post(
      url,
      JSON.stringify(params),
      onResponse,
      "text");
   };
```

Comment: You don't show how the method is called.

Comment: `$.post` is passed the url corresponding to test as defined in urls.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two URLs that are printed show exactly what is happening. You are posting to a URL without a final slash, but you have the default APPEND_SLASH setting, so Django is redirecting to the URL with a final slash appended. Redirects are always GETs.

Make sure you post to the URL with the slash.